# Delphi 7 strange disappearance of FormCreate event handler in dfm

Tags: delphi, tortoisesvn, delphi-7, dfm

I'm using Tortoise SVN with Delphi 7 and I always have to check the dfm before I commit... but I have a Delphi 7 DFM which has somehow lost it's FormCreate and FormShow event handles! I know that moving the form inside the Delphi IDE causes the dfm to be modified (Top, Left.. etc), but I highly doubt that I removed the event handles manually... so I'm wondering if anyone has experienced anything like this before. Please share your experience. Thanks.

Comment: Never happened to me. What does happen to me is that inherited properties (VFI) of an in-house custom component get messed up. Anyway, you should always check all files before you commit. If you don't you'll just leave in funny debugging code by mistake!

Comment: Nope, it wasn't me. My colleague just noticed it happening to him. That's 3 people in my team who have noticed this.

Comment: it happened to, many years ago, but I clearly remember that.

Comment: Well, just now the very same issue happened inside my XE4 IDE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sometimes happens, but do not know why. Mostly when using frames or inherited forms, and opening/changing a subframe/subform without opening the forms that use it. Or something like that... Cannot reproduce it, but weird indeed.

Comment: It just so happens that this issue happened around the time we introduced a new inherited base form.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Delphi for many years and it has never happened to me, but if the code is still there you could just double click on the event (FormCreate and FormShow) and they will be assigned again.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced this when initially sketching out the method and event structure. If I generate event handles, then move on and compile or run the program with an empty event holder, then CodeComplete will remove the empty handler. I have not encountered this problem in situations where the event handler is non-empty.